# Display full file name for icons on desktop

Tags: windows, desktop

In Windows, if a file name on the Desktop is greater than a set number of  characters, the name is truncated and an ellipsis (`...`) appears.

Is there anyway to always display the full file name?

Answer (score 6):

**For Windows XP** (later versions covered in this post)

The file names are truncated because the icons only have a certain amount of vertical and horizontal area assigned to them.

[image: Icon Settings in XP]

You may want to check out a little utility named [DeskView](http://jimcofer.com/personal/?p=208):

> Deskview.exe changes your desktop icons from “large icons” to “small icons.

[image: Deskview Results]

**For later version of Windows**

In later versions of Windows, follow the same guide for Windows XP but the Advanced Appearance exists in **either**:

> Control Panel -> Display -> Change color scheme link -> Advanced
>
> Control Panel -> Personalization -> Window Color and Appearance -> Advanced appearance settings...

When you change the size, you must click on apply, clicking OK will not have any affect (until after PC restarts). Also, you need to change the `icon spacing`.

It should also be noted that, if your screen is totally full of icons then changing the size may not help!

Comment: Does this work in Windows 7 as well?

Comment: Made an edit to work with later versions of Windows as well, and updated OP to make it more broad to Windows and not just WinXP

Comment: @Dave so in short it is not possible. I tried to change the size of my icons (which I would like to avoid), but text stayed the same shortened.

Comment: See my update @zx8754

Comment: @Dave great thank you for your help, I will have to restart then.